# Maximizing an integer Linear problem

Tags: linear-programming

i am taking a basic Linear programming class this semester and we've recently started solving integer linear problems. I have a question regarding how to solve one of these exercises.

$$
z = max\: 5x_{1} - 7x_{2} - 10x_{3} + 3x_{4} - 5x_{5}
$$
$$
s.t. \: x_{1} + 3x_{2} - 5x_{3} + x_{4} + 4x_{5} \leq 0
$$
$$
-2x_{1} - 6x_{2} + 3x_{3} - 2x_{4} - 2x_{5} \leq -4
$$
$$
2x_{2} - 2x_{3} - x_{4} + x_{5} \leq -2
$$
$$
x_{i}\in \left \{ 0, 1 \right \} \: i\in \left \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \right \}
$$

So far we've done cutting-plane and branch and bound. The way i'm thinking of solving this is by relaxing the integer constraint and using simplex to find the optimal non integer value. After i find it i can then apply the cutting-plane method and find the most optimal integer solution. The problem is that my teacher told me that i have to "simplify the problem by adding logical constraints or by simple logic". So that would mean that there is a way to simplify this system before starting to solve it?

Comment: We can't tell you what your teacher has in mind.  You'll have to ask them.  The requirements seem unclear: of course one way to solve such a system is to enumerate all $2^5$ possible assignments, but it seems your teacher doesn't want that.  I suggest you ask your teacher, rather than asking here.

Comment: You might want to multiply the first constraint by 2 and then add it to the second constraint. From that, you can figure out the value of $x_3$ and $x_5$.

Comment: If i were to take this approach would that put me at 2 constraints instead of 3, first one being: 7x3 - 6x5 >=4 and the second: -2x2 + 2x3 + x4 - x5 >=2 ? I didn't know it was possible to simplify problems by reducing the constraints through adding them.

Comment: @Daere The original constraints will always be there. You can take a linear combination of constraints to simplify the problem. The new constraints are just implications of older ones.